# Strip special characters except underscore and generate exact output as input in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to strip special characters from the object list, also generate same output format as input.

```
obj= {"col1": "es_officer_id", "col2": "es_officer_name", "col3": "es_officer_fname"};

var test = [];

for (var prop in obj)
{
     test.push(obj[prop].replace(/[^_ a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ''));
}

return test;
```

**Problem No 1:**

it gives me this error where as if i try this same .replace with string it works absolutely fine

```
TypeError: obj[prop].replace is not a function
```

**Problem No 2:**

I've tried to output the objects in the following format but it didn't work.
it gives me the prop as it it instead of col1, col2, col3

```
test.push({prop: obj[prop]});
```

Comment: Do you want `test` to be an array? Or an object like the input?

Comment: I want it to be object,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that others libraries or code is not doing all your objects dirty, try this:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
     test.push(obj[prop].replace(/[^_ a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ''));
  } 
}
```

The second problem you can create a new hash:

```
var test = {}
for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
     test[prop]=obj[prop].replace(/[^_ a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Be good to expand on why to use hasOwnProperty(). Definitely the "best practice" answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah i know there are libraries, like lodash underscore, stripchar but i don't wana use it, please tell me something, it is driving me nuts, when i send the exact object from browser it works fine, but when i send it from postman to API it gives me this error TypeError: obj[prop].replace is not a function I've checked the data again and agian but its copy and paste, why is it happening any idea ?

Comment: I didn't suggest to add a library. I think you have already another library or code that is changing the prototype of your objects. Try this:
`Object.prototype.test =  function(){}; var obj = {}; for (var prop in obj) {console.log(prop)}`  You can see test in your code. For this reason, you should use hasOwnProperty @Wcan I think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is not a problem, I simply copied your code and it worked.

Second problem can be solved by creating an object and adding property to that object adn then pushing it to target array.

```
obj= {"col1": "es_officer_id", "col2": "es_officer_name", "col3": "es_officer_fname"};

var test = [], test2 = [];

for (var prop in obj)
{
  test.push(obj[prop].replace(/[^_ a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ''));
  var d = {};
  d[prop] = obj[prop];
  test2.push(d);
}
console.log(test, test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj= {"col1": "es_officer_id%$^", "col2": "es_officer_name", "col3": "es_officer_fname"};

var test = [];

for (var prop in obj)
{
     test.push(obj[prop].replace(/[^_ a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ''));
}

document.body.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(test)
```

changed `obj=`... to `var obj=`...